# How to CSS a div class inside a div class when one class name exist elsewhere?

Tags: css

Have a webpage where we can't alter the HTML but we can add custom CSS. My issue is to set CSS to the div class="pull-right", but it must only apply to the class "pull-right" within the div class "col-sm-6 col-xs-12", becuase there is a div on a different page which also use the same class name. I assumed I could use:

```
.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.pull-right {
position: absolute;
left: 21%;
top: 600%;
}
```

But nothing happens (but it works if I only use .pull-right {... but affect also the other page).
Below is the code, How would the proper CSS be?:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="pull-right" style="display: table; padding-bottom: 8px;">
    <span style="display: table-cell; padding-right: 1em; width: 90px; vertical-align: middle;">kr 115,00 x</span>
    <span style="display: table-cell; width: 75px; border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">1</span>
    <span style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 1em; width: 95px; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;">= kr 115,00</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be:

```
.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 .pull-right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 21%;
    top: 600%;
}
```

Connecting classes together is done only when they're applied to the same element. Separate with a space when dealing with a child of preceding element.

Answer (score 1):

Since `.pull-right` is a direct child of `.col-sm-6.col-xs-12` , I would use this selector:

```
.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 > div.pull-right {
  [...]
}
```